# Outlook Addin Dialog API issue

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have been trying to use Dialog box for authentication. The dialog box is opening but not sending back message via messageParent API, however there is not problem when displayInIframe is added to dialog properties. But we cannot use Iframe for authentication.

Here is the function calling dialog,

```
function openDialog() {
    console.log("openDialog");
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("https://localhost:3000/src/auth/auth.html ", { height: 50, width: 50, promptBeforeOpen: false }, dialogCallback);
}
```

A part of web.config file

```
module.exports = async(env, options) => {
    const dev = options.mode === "development";
    const config = {
        devtool: "source-map",
        entry: {
            polyfill: "@babel/polyfill",
            taskpane: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.js",
            commands: "./src/commands/commands.js",
            auth: "./src/auth/auth.js"
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"]
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        options: {
                            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: "html-loader"
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                    use: "file-loader"
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                filename: "taskpane.html",
                template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
                chunks: ["polyfill", "taskpane"]
            }),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
                to: "taskpane.css",
                from: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.css"
            }]),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                filename: "commands.html",
                template: "./src/commands/commands.html",
                chunks: ["polyfill", "commands"]
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                filename: "auth.html",
                template: "./src/auth/auth.html",
                chunks: ["polyfill", "dialog"]
            }),
        ],
        devServer: {
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            },
            https: (options.https !== undefined) ? options.https : await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions(),
            port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000
        }
    };
```

Here is the simple auth.js file I am using for debugging,

```
Office.initialize = function() {
  $('#button1').click(one);
};

function one() {
    console.log("picked 1");
    Office.context.ui.messageParent("Picked 1");
    console.log("picked");
    // Both the console lines are working in new window but messageParent not returning message
}
```

Comment: You need an AppDomain entry in your manifest with https colon slash slash localhost:3000.  Also ensure that *all* AppDomain entries have the protocol listed.

Comment: In which Platform are you facing this issue? Could you please share the manifest so that we can try to reproduce this issue from our side?

Comment: pastebin.com/NX5TiVdv 
Please have a look at the manifest file.I am using this add-in on outlook.live.com in google chrome.
@OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT

Comment: We are not able to repro this issue from our side. Since you have mentioned that it works with iframe set to yes, we assume you have implemented  handler addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, callback); in order to receive and process the message send by parent as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.dialog?view=word-js-preview#addeventhandler-eventtype--handler-.  
The received message will appear in the developer console of the Parent window if you are verifying it using console.log(). Please ensure  this.

Comment: Let us know if the above comment helps. If not, do share the code used to verify the message send by parent window.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hT5tBrdD

I have implemented EventHandler already, Please have a look at my code .@OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT

Comment: we.tl/t-EZ2mprBmwX

Here is the whole folder , so that you can try and reproduce the problem . Please sort out this issue , I have been trying myself for weeks, @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT

Comment: Try adding ' <AppDomain>https//:localhost:3000</AppDomain> 'to your manifest and see if the issue gets resolved